# Mac Terminal space in path

Tags: terminal, path, whitespace, cd

I'm trying to cd to a location I get from pkgutil.

```
cd $(pkgutil --files com.company.pkg | grep company | sed 's/\company.aaxplugin.*//g'| uniq | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')
```

The output of

```
pkgutil --files com.company.pkg
```

is

```
Library
Library/Application Support
Library/Application Support/Avid
Library/Application Support/Avid/Audio
Library/Application Support/Avid/Audio/Plug-Ins
Library/Application Support/Avid/Audio/Plug-Ins/company.aaxplugin
Library/Application Support/Avid/Audio/Plug-Ins/company.aaxplugin/Contents
...
```

I use grep, sed and unique to get to:

```
Library/Application Support/Avid/Audio/Plug-Ins
```

Now I can't figure out a way to cd to that directory.. I tried putting quotes around the path, storing it in a variable, replacing " " with "\ " etc..

Any tips?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So the output of `pkgutil --files com.company.pkg | grep company | sed 's/\company.aaxplugin.*//g'| uniq | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g'`  is `Library/Application Support/Avid/Audio/Plug-Ins`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test the exact commands you have because I don't have those packages installed, but I was simulating output with spaces and got it to work.

```
$ cd "$(echo /Library/Application Support)"
```

was able to take me to the `/Library/Application Support/` directory in both bash and zsh.

Thus, in your case, you'd want to surround the entire `$(`...`)` with `"`.

```
cd "$(pkgutil --files com.company.pkg | grep company | sed 's/\company.aaxplugin.*//g'| uniq | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Piccolo!
Apparently I put the " in the wrong spot.